# Magento 2.4.4 error in setup:upgrade

Tags: database, setup-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I completed successfully composer update magento 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4

Also my template and all modules are ready for 2.4.4 magento

But in setup:upgrade

I got this:

```
Unable to apply data patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4650-1028-0' for key 'catalog_product_entity_text.CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ROW_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_entity_text` (`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`row_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?),
```

and the ? continue more and more.

I search in this table: `catalog_product_entity_text`
For duplicate but I cannot identify any.

Has anyone faced this error?
Any solution please?

Comment: did have bundle products?

Comment: try with  $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertOnDuplicate,

Comment: @S.P I don't have bundle product. Only simple and configurable

Comment: @S.P Also I don't understand exactly where to put your code please? In which line?

Comment: I am not sure but magento previous 2.4.4 have not vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes.php file.

Check in UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes.php file

Comment: @S.P. Check what? I have that file there UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes.php

Comment: Line num:90 
 $connection->insertMultiple($textTable, $dataChunk); There?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136096/discussion-between-g-g-and-s-p).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue after migrate of Magento version.
I was used **insertOnDuplicate** .

Update magento file.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes.php

around line num:89 you will find

```
foreach (array_chunk($dataToMigrate, 2000) as $dataChunk) {
    $connection->insertMultiple($textTable, $dataChunk);
}
```

use **insertOnDuplicate** there.

```
foreach (array_chunk($dataToMigrate, 2000) as $dataChunk) {
    foreach($dataChunk as $single) {
        $connection->insertOnDuplicate($textTable, $dataChunk);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason this issue still exists if it's a known Magento code bug as I am running into the same issue now?

Comment: Shouldn't this be ```$connection->insertOnDuplicate($textTable, $single);```  ?

Comment: After applying this change , the setup:upgrade command is stuckes and never stops.
Unable to apply data patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `mgcp_catalog_product_entity_text` (`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES

Comment: @Kishor6ugani     Check with your custom module disabled. If you have recent added any custom module then disable it and check.

Comment: disabled all the 3rd party modules , but still setup:upgrade stuck on Magento_Catalog

Comment: check log files ( before clear it). If you disabled all module then issue would be from DB side.

Check new created table and check whitelist.

php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=YourModule_Name

Comment: php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=YourModule_Name

Comment: I have not installed any new modules , but I upgrade my site to 2.4.6-p1 , then this issue will arise

Comment: Check in your local instance.

rename vendor folder and re-install magento with composer.