# error while upgrading from Magento 2.2.3 to Magento 2.4.4 in setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2.2.3 to Magento 2.4.4 and successfully composer updated the setup and have all other modules updated as well but while running setup:upgrade command, i got this error:

`` Unable to apply data patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '109760-972-0' for key 'CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID', query was: INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_entity_text` (`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ``

I tried to patch the *vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes.php* file using this solution [Magento 2.4.4 error in setup:upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355539/magento-2-4-4-error-in-setupupgrade) and yes this error was gone but the process stuck for forever on Module 'Magento_Catalog'. I tried several times but again and again same thing.

Comment: Try backing up the DB, then go to catalog_product_entity_text table and delete entry with entity_id = 109760, attribute_id = 972 and store_id = 0

Comment: yes i already did and after that one more shows up and so on but there is no duplicates there in the existing table.

Comment: @CvK, any idea how you resolved this issue as I am running into the same issue? I want to avoid making changes to out of the box code if possible.

Comment: have you solved it @CvGandhi

Comment: used this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355539/magento-2-4-4-error-in-setupupgrade but i dumped the conflicting rows.

Comment: hi @CvGandhi can you please share what you do in Db?
I deleted the rows, but it never end one after another coming in setup:upgrade command, and solution you mentioned is stucked on Magento_Catalog, Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue and the following solution helped me.
Try to replace

```
        foreach (array_chunk($dataToMigrate, 2000) as $dataChunk) {
            $connection->insertMultiple($textTable, $dataChunk);
        }
```

with

```
        foreach (array_chunk($dataToMigrate, 500) as $dataChunk) {
            try {
                $connection->insertMultiple($textTable, $dataChunk);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                foreach($dataChunk as $single) {
                    $connection->insertOnDuplicate($textTable, $dataChunk);
                }
            }
        }
```

File: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/Patch/Data/UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes.php
Line ~90.

Comment: Is this a known bug or none else reported this so far since you're suggesting to make changes to out of box code here?

Comment: hi @cnu have you find any solution?

Comment: @Kishor6ugani no, as a quick fix modified out of the box code for testing the upgrade.

Comment: can you share that code ? @cnu

Answer (score 0):

Did anybody fix this, we're upgrading from 2.4.5 to 2.4.6 and getting the same issue. We the code linked to by post and the extra code in this thread it just hangs on 'Magento_Catalog'.

Comment: have you solved it , I am facing same issue