# Magento 2 After Upgrade Error Unable to apply data patch Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, upgrade, catalog, patches

After Upgrading to Magento 2.4.6.-p1 , we are getting error on `setup:upgrade`

> Unable to apply data patch
> Magento\Catalog\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateMultiselectAttributesBackendTypes
> for module Magento_Catalog. Original exception message:
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '5566-200-0' for key
> 'MGCP_CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_TEXT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID',
> query was: INSERT  INTO `mgcp_catalog_product_entity_text`
> (`value_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES

Tried this [Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355539/magento-2-4-4-error-in-setupupgrade) but it stucks on Magento_catalog in setup :upgrade

please help me about this.